# Losing a value from pointer vector after loop that reads the file (using dirent)

Tags: c++, file, pointers, vector

I'm writing a program in C++ that behaves like a Twitter Service. The program is supposed to store data in files as follows:

f_username (stores the users that username follows), so it creates a file for each user that follows someone. I have the function load_users() that reads each file to populate all clients (users) information in a vector called client_db (global variable) of type struct (defined below). So, when a f_username file is read, the vectors client_followers and client_following are populated for each user. The function works perfectly, except for the first file it reads. It saves the information in client_followers and client_following in the while loop that reads the file, but the entries for both vectors are deleted somehow after this loop. I added the comments in the code where I'm facing this issue only for the first f_username file it reads.

I believe it has something to do with the fact I'm using pointers, but I have no clue how to fix this issue. This is the first time ever I have this weird logic error. How is possible that it only "deletes" the data from the vectors that is read from first file, but not from the other files (I have 3 files)?

Any help would be really appreciated, I tried my best to explain this problem.

**UPDATE: Problem fixed by replacing the types of vectors client_followers and client_following with a string type without declaring them as pointers, and making sure the actual entries in client_db are updated correctly. **

```
    //Client struct that holds a user's username, followers, and users they follow
struct Client {
    std::string username;
    bool connected = false;
    int following_file_size = 0;
    std::vector<Client*> client_followers;
    std::vector<Client*> client_following;

    ServerReaderWriter<Message, Message>* stream = 0;

    bool operator==(const Client& c1) const{
        return (username == c1.username);
    }
};

void load_users()
{
    //load users (followers and following)
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir ("./")) != NULL) {
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            std::string filename = ent->d_name;
            int index = filename.find("f_");
            if(index != std::string::npos)
            {

                std::ifstream in; //read following file of username

                //get username
                std::string user = filename.substr(index+2);
                int txt_index = user.find(".txt");
                user.erase(txt_index,4);

                int user_index = find_user(user); //check if user is in client's db already
                //client_db is a global variable
                if(user_index < 0){ //if not, add client to client_db
                    Client c;
                    c.username = user;
                    client_db.push_back(c);
                }

                Client* user1 = &client_db[find_user(user)];
                std::string username2;

                in.open("./" + filename);
                while(!in.eof())
                {
                    getline(in,username2);

                    int following_index = find_user(username2);
                    if(following_index < 0) //create entry for the user
                    {
                        Client c2;
                        c2.username = username2;
                        client_db.push_back(c2);
                    }
                    Client* user2 = &client_db[find_user(username2)];
                    //it adds the information for the first file, but entries in client_followers
                    //and client_following is deleted after this loop ends, how is this possible?
                    user2->client_followers.push_back(user1);
                    user1->client_following.push_back(user2);

                }
                //When I print information of client_following and client_followers, the information obtained from the first file is not printed (e.g. size of client_following is 0).
                in.close();
                //break;
            }
        }
        closedir (dir);
    } else {
        /* could not open directory */
        //perror ("");
        //return EXIT_FAILURE;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns -1 if the username is not in client_db, otherwise it returns at least 0 (i.e. the position of the user in the client_db).

Comment: Since `client_db` is a `std::vector`, when adding new values to a vector reallocation may occur, with the vector essentially copying its contents into a new, bigger vector. This moves all the contents in the vector, and since your objects store pointers to each other, hillarity ensues, as these pointers now point to deleted objects. The answer to your question: "keep reading your C++ book until you fully understand how pointers work", then redesign your data structures accordingly. This is too big of a subject to fit into a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand pointers, but the code was provided by the professor with the struct client declared as given here. I was trying not to making changes to the data structures, but due to the issue using pointers, I had to use vector of strings for followers and following without declaring them as pointers. It fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing in my comment that implied that the `Client` struct must be changed in any way, whatsoever. The problem is not with the `Client` struct.